# PC - Sleeping Dogs: (Definitive Edition) Radio Fix

Tags: steam, pc, sleeping-dogs

Hey guys I recently bought Sleeping Dogs: Definitive Edition on PC through Steam as it was on sale. I've played the normal edition when it was released and one of the good parts of the game was the car radio.

Right now I am having problems with the car radio volume. For some odd reason the car radio volume always resets back to 0 when I change it to 10. It's really boring to drive in the game without my favorite radio station playing. Is there a fix for the problem I am having?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be easily solved by just setting the radio volume with left and right arrow keys and then it saves, such a weird bug.

Comment: Do you mean rebinding the keys?

Comment: No, I mean you got to the options -> audio and there under car radio volume you set the desired volume with arrow keys on your keyboard instead setting them with the mouse. And then it should save the settings when you confirm them. This totally worked for me.